# Calculate percentage of amount using SQL returning values in rows instead of columns

Tags: sql, pivot, presto

I am trying to find allocation percentage of assets, as to how much % of stocks, cash and bond, of a customer at account level.

**portfolio table:**

| account_no | ticker | portfolio_type | port_percent | position_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ARKG | Stock | 10 | 100 |
| 1 | ARKG | Cash | 90 | 100 |
| 1 | ARKG | Bond | 0 | 100 |
| 1 | AAPL | Stock | 100 | 200 |
| 2 | TSLA | Stock | 100 | 50 |

**SQL used:**

```
with total_position_amt as
(
select account_no,
sum(distinct position_amt) as total_position_amt
from portfolio
group by account_no
)
derived_balance as
(
select account_no,
portfolio_type,
(port_percent*position_amt)/100 as total_derived_balance
from portfolio
)
select account_no,
portfolio_type,
(sum(total_derived_balance)/total_position_amt)*100 as asset_percent
from derived_balance a
inner join total_position_amt b
on a.account_no = b.account_no
group by account_no, portfolio_type, position_amt
```

The above sql returns the value as rows instead of columns which is not what i was expecting.

**Incorrect output:**

| account_no | portfolio_Type | asset_Percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stock | 70 |
| 1 | Cash | 30 |
| 1 | Bond | 0 |
| 2 | Stock | 100 |

**Expected output:**

| account_no | stock_percent | Cash_Percent | Bond_Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 70 | 30 | 0 |
| 2 | 100 | 0 | 0 |

Please advise how I can achieve the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of aggregating, computing values separately and joining two partial outputs, you can compute your values using window functions in two common table expressions:

- first cte will transform to NULL all successive duplicate values of position_amt using the `LAG` function
- second cte will divide sum of total_derived_balance per portfolio by the sum over the total_position_amt, and get the "*asset_Percent*"

Last step, which is missing to your current query as well, is applying the pivot, by selecting values from the "*portfolio_Type*" field, using `CASE` statements and apply aggregation.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT account_no,
           portfolio_type,
           (port_percent*position_amt)/100 as total_derived_balance,
           CASE WHEN LAG(position_amt) OVER(
                         PARTITION BY account_no, position_amt 
                         ORDER     BY position_amt) IS NULL 
                THEN position_amt 
           END AS total_position_amt
    FROM portfolio
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT account_no, portfolio_type,
           ROUND(100.0 * SUM(total_derived_balance) OVER(
                             PARTITION BY account_no, portfolio_type) 
                       / SUM(total_position_amt) OVER(
                             PARTITION BY account_no                )) AS asset_Percent
    FROM cte
)
SELECT account_no,
       MAX(CASE WHEN portfolio_type = 'Stock' 
                THEN asset_Percent ELSE 0     END) AS Stock_Percent,
       MAX(CASE WHEN portfolio_type = 'Cash' 
                THEN asset_Percent ELSE 0     END) AS Cash_Percent,
       MAX(CASE WHEN portfolio_type = 'Bond' 
                THEN asset_Percent ELSE 0     END) AS Bond_Percent
FROM cte2
GROUP BY account_no
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6pgEbUsbkKxZq2SQoZxt9F/1).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Let me try executing this and get back.

Comment: I tried executing the demo. The values are getting doubled. For account_no 1, I see stock percentage as 140 instead of 70

Comment: You're right, use `MAX` in place of `SUM`, in the last part of the query. I've updated the link at the bottom of the answer as well.

Comment: Yes, I modified it to MAX and it worked for me. Thanks a lot for the answer. One question. With the lag function to derive total_position_amt and subsequent sum on it, does sum of a number with blank or null result in number? Do we add else condition on lag?

Comment: We don't need to add the `ELSE` condition: that will translate into having NULL values. In this way we're removing the duplicates you have in "*position_amt*", that we don't really need. I'd suggest you to look at intermediate steps. I'll leave you [another fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6pgEbUsbkKxZq2SQoZxt9F/1): it's sufficient to change the last row of the code with 'FROM cte', 'FROM cte2' or 'FROM cte3'.

Comment: Thanks. I did select * from cte and I see 100, null, null in total_position amount. In cte2, when we perform SUM(total_position_amt), which means (100 + null + null), it should result in null i  thought.

Comment: NULL values are transformed to 0 when the aggregate function is `SUM`.

Comment: Ah nice ! TIL :) Thank you so much. Learned a lot here